# Move a pointer location around to write a recursively allocated buffer

Tags: c, void-pointers

Apologies if the title doesn't make sense, I've been staring at my monitor for 15 minutes trying to come up with one.

I'm using a library function from a C API (in 64-bit Xubuntu 14.04) to move a set number of int16_t values into a buffer and repeat it a set number of times, described here in (sort of) pseudo-code:

```
int16_t *buffer = calloc(total_values_to_receive, 2 * sizeof(samples[0]));

while (!done){

    receive_into_buffer(buffer, num_values_to_receive_per_pass);

    fwrite(buffer, 2 * sizeof(samples[0]), num_values_to_receive_per_pass, file);

    values_received += num_values_to_receive_per_pass;
    if (values_received == total_values_to_receive){
        done  = true;
    }
}
```

Basically what it does is receive a set number of values on each pass and writes those values to a file, also note that the same file is appended each time. E.g. if `total_values_to_receive = 100` and `num_values_to_receive_per_pass = 10`, there would be 10 passes in total.

What I would like to do, mainly to increase speed, is to have the write part occur after all passes have been completed. The library function prototype contains `void* samples, size_t num_samples`, which, you guessed it, refers to the buffer where the samples need to be stored into and the amount of samples to store.

I'm not completely confident with pointers, but is there a way to write into the buffer on one pass, and then move the pointer by `num_values_to_receive_per_pass` so that the next time the library function is called, it just appends that buffer (so to speak). Then the pointer can be moved to the start of the buffer and `fwrite` can be called to write the total number of values into the file.

Does that make sense? Any tips on how to actually implement it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the second argument of `receive_into_buffer` is in unit of buffer element, not byte, the following should work,

```
int16_t *buffer = calloc(total_values_to_receive, 2 * sizeof(buffer[0]));
int16_t *temp = buffer;

while (!done){
    receive_into_buffer(temp, num_values_to_receive_per_pass);
    temp += 2 * num_values_to_receive_per_pass;

    values_received += num_values_to_receive_per_pass;
    if (values_received == total_values_to_receive){
        done  = true;
    }
}
fwrite(buffer, 2 * sizeof(buffer[0]), total_values_to_receive, file);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it was very helpful. However, the values that I'm expecting to find in the buffer aren't there, comparing between my previous implementation of writing to file after each `receive_into_buffer` has completed. Something may be going wrong under the hood (since it is a library function), I'll do some more testing to confirm.

Comment: @user2742907 You're welcome. What's the type of `samples` in the call to `calloc`?

Comment: That's a type, it should be buffer[0], thus also int16_t.

Comment: Any reason why you need to multiply it by 2?

Comment: It's because one buffer element (representing one sample) consists of 2 int16_t values, a real and imaginary part. It's just a convention I'm using to keep me from losing my mind when keeping track of stuff.

Comment: Okay, I've edited the answer based on what you just told me. Notice that I've also added a factor of 2 to the pointer addition.

Comment: I see, thanks again. I'll go through it again to try and wrap my head around it and just to make sure that I know what I'm doing. I'll report my findings in a while.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62948/discussion-between-user2742907-and-downhillfromhere).

Answer (score 1):

Style: a plain for() loop will avoid the indicator variable:

```
for (values_receive=0; values_received < total_values_to_receive; values_received += num_values_to_receive_per_pass) {

    receive_into_buffer(buffer, num_values_to_receive_per_pass);

    fwrite(buffer, 2 * sizeof(samples[0]), num_values_to_receive_per_pass, file);

}
```